Label at left of each align line
I have an align environment like this:
\begin{align}
P(x,y): && f(some) \cdot f(thing) & = f(some) \cdot thing \\
P(0,0): && f(0) \cdot f(0) = f(0) \cdot 0 \\
&& \Rightarrow f(0) & = 0
\end{align}

I want the actual equation to be centered in the line (which is standard behavior already) but I want the label (the P(x,y):) to be excluded of the line width, so it wont affect the position of the line. Instead it should be placed at the very left of the text body. It would also be fine if the equation would be centered within the remaining width of the line (after the label), but in my use case both parts are short enough that they wouldn't overlap if the equation would be centered within the whole line.

Can you add an image to show the desired effect? Thank you.

I believe flalign environment is what you are looking for

\documentclass{article} %leqno
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{flalign}
    &P(x,y): & f(some) \cdot f(thing) &= f(some) \cdot thing &\\
    &P(0,0): &    f(0) \cdot f(0) &= f(0) \cdot 0 &\\
    &        & \Rightarrow f(0) &= 0 &
\end{flalign}
\end{document}

